# Cant set Features or Epics to active in Azure Devops Server

Tags: azure-devops, agile

We rolled ADS out as our main development platform a few months ago and generally have be working pretty well in it.  However, one of the things I've noticed is I (project admin) am unable to set Epics or Features to a state outside of "New", "Close", or "Removed".  The feature I added a picture of has 2 child user stories - one of which is "Active" and one which is "Resolved".  It also has a parent Epic which is set to "new" because I'm unable to change the state of that one to Active either. As far as I can tell, I've added all the information I can to the feature, and based on the Microsoft documentation it appears I should have more states available but can't figure out what I'm missing.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Are you sure that you have defined state which you want to use in your Process definition?

Process name that you currently use in your project can be found here https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganizationName/ProjectName/_settings/

Process states definition can be found here https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganizationName -> Organization Settings -> Boards -> Process ->  -> <Select 'Feature' work item> -> States

2 - Maybe someone has restricted state transition creating new rule for your process? Like in this example?
[image]

Documentation regarding this can be found here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops#restrict-state-transitions

Comment: I think thats the issue. It appears someone who has Organization security access changed the process without informing us. Thank you for your help!